# Django: problem declarig 2 fields with the same related object

Tags: django, django-models

I'm trying to create a model that has 2 fields with the same related object (**Call**):

```
class Call(LogsMixin, models.Model):
    """Definición del modelo de Proveedor."""

    id = models.CharField("ID de la convocatoria", primary_key=True, null=False, default="", max_length=50)
    name = models.CharField("Nombre de convocatoria", null=False, default="", max_length=200)
    active = models.BooleanField("Activada", default=True)


class Consumption(LogsMixin, models.Model):
    """Definición del modelo de Consumos"""

    client = models.ForeignKey('authentication.Client', verbose_name=("Cliente"), null=True, default=None, on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT)
    sap_price = models.DecimalField(("Precio de SAP"), max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, null=False, default=0)
    access_date = models.DateField("Fecha de acceso", auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    call = models.ForeignKey(Call, verbose_name=("Convocatoria"), null=True, default=None, on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT)
    accessible_calls = models.ManyToManyField(Call, verbose_name=("Convocatorias accesibles"))
```

When I try to make the migrations I receive the next error:

> ERRORS: consumptions.Consumption.accessible_calls: (fields.E304)
> Reverse accessor for 'Consumption.accessible_calls' clashes with
> reverse accessor for 'Consumption.call'.
> HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'Consumption.accessible_calls' or 'Consumption.call'.
> consumptions.Consumption.call: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for
> 'Consumption.call' clashes with reverse accessor for
> 'Consumption.accessible_calls'.
> HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'Consumption.call' or 'Consumption.accessible_calls'.

**And yes, I read the HINT, but it's not what I need**

I need this because I need the call that the client selected and the calls that he can choose

Does anyone have any clue?

Comment: HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'Consumption.accessible_calls' or 'Consumption.call'. consumptions.Consumption.call

Comment: Won't work, is not what I want

Comment: What do you mean it won't work, it is clear that you have two clashing related_names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two fields with same reverse [related_name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name)  that are automatically constructed by Django as `call_set`

you should change one of them to unique value

```
accessible_calls = models.ManyToManyField(Call, verbose_name=("Convocatorias accesibles", related_name="my_related_name"))
```